# leaflet shiny. Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I Have a dataset with some indicators, years and regions. Im trying to display the information in a leaflet coropleth map in shiny. For that I have created two selectInput: one to choose the indicator and another to choose the year.
I can get the map when not use shiny, simply filtering indicator and year. However in shiny Im getting: "Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'". Someone could help me??

#########################

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)    
library(leaflet)  
library(RSocrata)
library(dplyr)
library(raster)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

spain <-  getData("GADM", country="ESP", level=1)
optdata <- read_excel("D:\\Documents and Settings\\05635062Q\\Mis documentos\\GHEALTH\\optdata.xlsx")

# get ratio women/men
optdata_mean <- optdata%>%
  select('indicator_id', 'year', 'sex', 'measure',  'trend_axis',   'indicator',    'interpret', 
         'type_definition', 'profile',  'areaname', 'areatype', 'code')%>%
  group_by(year,indicator, areaname, sex, code, profile)%>%
  summarise(Total_mean=mean(measure)) 


optdata_ratio <-spread(optdata_mean, sex, Total_mean)%>%mutate(ratio=round(Mujeres/Hombres,2))
optdata_ratio <- optdata_ratio%>%rename("women" = "Mujeres",  "men" = "Hombres")

###############################################.
## Adding a new column in geo dataset necessary for use the map ----
###############################################.
optdata_ratio <- optdata_ratio%>%
  mutate(
    HASC_1 = case_when(
      code == "01"  ~ 'ES.AN',
      code == "02"  ~ 'ES.AR', 
      code == "03"  ~ 'ES.AS',
      code == "04"  ~ 'ES.PM',
      code == "05"  ~ 'ES.CN',
      code == "06"  ~ 'ES.CB',
      code == "07"  ~ 'ES.CL',
      code == "08"  ~ 'ES.CM',
      code == "09"  ~ 'ES.CT',
      code == "10"  ~ 'ES.VC',
      code == "11"  ~ 'ES.EX',
      code == "12"  ~ 'ES.GA',
      code == "13"  ~ 'ES.MD',
      code == "14"  ~ 'ES.MU',
      code == "15"  ~ 'ES.NA',
      code == "16"  ~ 'ES.PV',
      code == "17"  ~ 'ES.LO',
      code == "20"  ~ 'ES.ML',
      #ceuta and Melilla are considered one in the map data 
      
      TRUE ~  "OTHER"
    )
  )

indicator_se_list <-sort(optdata$indicator[optdata$profile %in% 
                                             c("socieconomic")])
indicator_health_list<-sort(optdata$indicator[optdata$profile %in% 
                                                c("health")])


########### SHINY APP ###########

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput("rate", label = "Select the socioeconomic indicator:",
                  choices=levels(df$Rate), selected = 1),
      
      # Select year according to what data is available
      shiny::hr(),
      uiOutput("year_ui_rank"),
      

    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map", height = "600")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

#Reactive expression for the data subsetted to what the user selected
  
output$year_ui_rank <- renderUI({
  time<- sort((df$Year[df$Rate == input$rate]))
  
  selectInput("year",label= shiny::HTML("<p>Select year <br/> <span style='font-weight: 400'></span></p>"),
              choices = time, selected = last(time))})

  
data_filtered <-reactive({
    
    d<-df%>%subset(Year==input$year  & Rate==input$rate)
    return(d)
    
  })

  
poly_map <- reactive({
    
    MergedData <- sp::merge(spain, data_filtered(), duplicateGeoms = TRUE, by.x = "HASC_1", by.y ="HASC_1") 
})

  
 
output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = poly_map()$Total_ratio, bins = bins)
   
    
  
    #create a pop up (onClick)
    polygon_popup <- paste0("<strong>Name: </strong>", spain$NAME_1, "<br>",
                            "<strong>Indicator: </strong>", poly_map()$Total_ratio)
    

    leaflet('map') %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
      setView(lng = -3.7, lat = 40.4, zoom = 06) %>% 
      addPolygons(data =  poly_map(), 
                  fillColor= ~pal(Total_ratio),
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,
                  highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.8,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                  label = labels,
                  popup = polygon_popup,
                  labelOptions = labelOptions(
                    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                    textsize = "15px",
                    direction = "auto"))%>%addLegend('bottomright',
                                                     opacity = 0.7,
                                                     pal = pal,
                                                     values =  poly_map()$Total_ratio)  
  })
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement from your `poly_map` function.  Does that help solve the problem?  If not, do you have any further information about *where* the error occurs.  If you can't tell from the error message or traveback, try commenting out parts of your code until the error disappears.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Where should I put the return?. I think the problem is in the selectInput. Another error that Im getting is 

Warning: Error in as.vector: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
  98: %>%
  97: ::

Comment: A reactive is a function, so the return goes in the same place that you'd want it to be in any other function.  Normally as the last line.  Indeed, that's exactly where it is in your `data_filtered` reactive.  And since your `poly_map` reactive is only one line long, you didn't have too many options you could have tried for yourself.